# How do I prevent promises from losing context without arrow function

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following code...

```
page.goToPage().then(() => page.isLoaded()).then(() => driver.quit());
```

This seems to be too verbose but when I try...

```
page.goToPage().then(page.isLoaded).then(driver.quit);
```

I get errors because in `page.isLoaded` the context of `this` changes to the promise.

Is there a way I can do the later without an arrow function?

Comment: Bind() it? `page.isLoaded.bind(page)`?

Comment: you could try `page.isLoaded.bind(page)` and `driver.quit.bind(driver)`

Comment: You can, but why? I don't see anything "too verbose" about that arrow notation. What I do see is an odd bit of promise code that's apparently not yielding data at the end of each step, for the next `then` to work with. Why is that?

Comment: Consider putting line breaks before your `.then` so that `.then` is on its own line.  Alternatively, use `async/await`.

Comment: You are using a method as a callback. Seems like an antipattern making error handling more complication. I see no advantage in doing that.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans A promise is being passed back from each step

Comment: No, *data*, not "the required promise to allow `then` chaining". Make `goToPage` supply `page` as data for the next handler. Make `isLoaded` (which should be named `waitForLoad` really) pass `driver` for the next handler, etc. You should need to hack your way into global scope, those `then` handlers should be given exactly what they need to do their job, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I wrote you up an answer that shows how you remove the need to worry about "the correct context" by making sure your promises return what they need to. And uses a `.catch()` because never, ever, write promise code without adding `.catch()` handlers =)

Comment: yeah I see what you mean but then I have to create new promises which is even more verbose eek!

Comment: I actually ended up refactoring a lot of the complexity into a global (window) RXjs subject that I could filter off of which seemed to be slightly easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use promises properly. There is nothing too verbose about arrow notation, but a good practice is to make sure that any `then` handler is provided with the information it needs to do the job you need it to do.

```
class Driver {
  quit() {
    console.log("quit");
  }
}

class Page {
  constructor() {
    this.driver = new Driver();
  }

  goToPage() {
    console.log("gotopage");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Things happen here. If they go wrong, you call reject() with an argument that
      // is a useful error object. If they succeed, you call resolve() with data that the
      // next handler should be working with. In this case I'm passing "this" so that the
      // page is available to the next link in the chain.
      resolve(this);
    });
  }

  waitForLoad() {
    console.log("waitforload");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // let's have this fail half the time, for demonstration purposes.
      var l = Math.random();
      if (l < 0.5) {
        resolve(this.driver);
      } else {
        reject(new Error("error"));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now, you have proper promise-using code:

```
var p = new Page();

p.goToPage()
 .then( page => page.waitForLoad())
 .then( driver => driver.quit())
 .catch( e => console.error(e));
```

Each `then` handler now gets exactly the input it needs to call the functions it needs to call, without trying to bust through their own scope, and without having to `.bind()` anything.

(If you need `.bind()` in normal code, that's usually the sign you are fighting against JavaScript in terms of ensuring sope, rather than making use of the various ways JavaScript lets you ensure correct scope)

Answer (score 0):

Like [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans) suggested after finding the answer it doesn't seem any less verbose...

```
page.goToPage()
    .then(page.isLoaded.bind(page))
    .then(driver.quit.bind(driver));
```

(Thanks @GetOffMyLawn)

I will leave the question unanswered in case someone has a creative solution.

Comment: You can, of course, assign bound function references and (on rare occasions) it can be advantageous to do so;
eg. in some suitable scope: `var foo = page.isLoaded.bind(page); var bar = driver.quit.bind(driver);` 
and `page.goToSomePage().then(foo).then(bar);` ... `page.goToSomeOtherPage().then(foo).then(bar);`.